# How to create a base64 file from nothing?

Tags: javascript, base64, data-uri, data-url

I want to be able to create base64 files (images, sounds, video) without any previous models. For example, if **I want to create a base64 64px*64px red image, how can I do this without creating first a canvas?**

I would also like to create a sound (note) with no model.

I've searched on Google for some documentation on base64 encoding but I did not seem to find specific things for my need.

I am going to use Javascript, but I guess this should be the same for every language.

Comment: base64 is just encoding format, it has no relation to data inside...

Comment: So my question is how do you code the data inside :)

Comment: It depends from format, and has no relation to base64... - before encoding you need to generate actual file data. For example if you want png image - likely you need to start from reading documentation about format, or look for existing implementations (canvas is pretty good example of such implementation :), not sure - but maybe there is implementations purely in JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function createFile(_data) {
  var _data = ["<!doctype html>", 
        "<img style=width:64px;height:64px;"
        + "background-color:red;display:block; />"];
  var data = window.btoa(_data.join("").toString());
  var file = "data:text/html;base64," + data;
  return file
};
createFile();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6GPju/

see also http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa