# Is it a good idea to store images in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a HTML/Javascript tool that does something with images. Frankly, I just use HTML because Java or C++ GUI is way too complicated and not worth the effort.

The tool just displays an image and then displays percentual and absolute coordinates as you hover the image:

[image: image description]

My aim is to create a little GUI for "Last images" allowing to quickly display recent image. And because the application is client-only, I can't use any kind of server storage. There's a `localStorage` object, but to me, it seems like a bad idea to store several MB of images in it.

What do you think? Should I use `localStorage` for that? Or is there an alternative? Or maybe the server cooperation is totally necessary?

Comment: You can use local storage and  save the image as a Base64 file.
But if the file is too big, local storage is not recommended. And you might need to use some back-end programmings. JS is not good at file manipulation.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it. But I'm not so sure that it's all-right to do it.

Comment: have you looked at File API? http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ http://html5demos.com/file-api

Comment: @Stuart Have you? As a matter of fact, I've read this document many times since I often meddle with files in javascript. This API doesn't provide any functions that allow you to save data actually (maybe except of possible invoking of saveAs dialog window)

Comment: Is requirement to save file , image to client ? If possible , can post `html` , `js` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Try this: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @TomášZato See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120177/save-json-file-locally/28122377#28122377 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html/28257733?s=6|0.9429#28257733 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227331/how-to-create-a-base64-file-from-nothing/24231030?s=14|0.6862#24231030 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826495/download-file-served-as-response/24829153#24829153

Answer (score 4):

You can use a compression algorithm to compress the base64 string representation of images. I used the similar approach in my code and it alowed me to store more images compared to normal case.

Compression lib: LZstring http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Comment: I wonder what's the purpose of base64 when another library then generates compressed data. Cannot the base64 just be ommited in that case?

Comment: LZstring compresses string data only. Also,  base64 will be lighter then actual image blob.

Answer (score 3):

It's either that or using the **HTML5 File API**, but if you are just saving a few images under 5mb [**HTML5 WebStorage**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) should be enough, like this:

If you use the web storage, and [**HTML5 Canvas**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) to convert the image into text (data uri):

```
var img = new Image();
   img.src = "same_origin.png";

localStorage.setItem("lastImage",imgToURI(img));


function imgToURI(img){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

And then for retrieving the saved image:

```
var last = new Image();
  last.src = localStorage.getItem("lastImage1");
```

**Note**: Most browsers only allow 5mb of local storage.

**Note**: While [**localStorage**](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) is highly supported, [**canvas**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas) it's not supported in IE8.

---

**Note**: The **HTML File API** approach wouldn't be user friendly, as of now Chrome is the only one allowing writing files with their **filesystem api**, for the other ones you'll have to convert the images to data uri, then make a link with all the data in the form of a data uri text file, and have the user download it and reload it every time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data